# How to rotate part of an svg?

Tags: svg, rotation

I'm trying to create an svg image where when you hover over part of an image it animates other parts of the image. It's a guitar pedal that when you hover over it, the light goes on and the dials rotate. However I can't figure out how to rotate the dials without the dials shooting off of the pedal. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Here's an example of it:

https://codepen.io/SHINZOC/pen/vYEaooM

```
    .lo { transition: .1s;}
    .lo:hover {opacity: 0;}
    #Light_off:hover + #Dials {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center center;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS to

```
.lo { transition: .1s;}
.lo:hover {opacity: 0;}
#Light_off:hover + #Dials {
transform: rotate(45deg);
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box:fill-box;
 }
```

since you want to rotate around the fill box and not the view box.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! Saved me a lot of frustration!